# Stop image caching in wP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I have a function which displays images from a binded uri (ie; www.website.com/picture1.jpg).

I have found and now understand that the phone caches the images that are downloaded. I read that its only for the life of the runng of the app, but even when I close the app and go back into it the same images from the cache come up. 
Is there a way to stop this caching happening at all for this particular page?

EDIT: The images update regularly, but still have the same name, hence the need not to cache. Think security camera for example.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way around it unless you add a random query string to the image uri on each GET i.e.

```
var imageUrl = "www.website.com/picture1.jpg";
var imageUri = new Uri(String.Format("{0}?{1}", imageUrl, Guid.NewGuid()));
```

The caching is a little too aggressive - If doing a GET to the same Uri on any http request for the applications life cycle - Even if the content changes every time - The phone will cache it. It kept me puzzled for hours when I was trying to talk to a JSON-RPC web service...

Of course in general you will want images to be cached - But if you're sure the images you're after will be changing frequently then  the above will work.

Comment: Thanks. Im not sure how to do this in my scenrio but I will work something out I hope. 
I still have some images stored from yesterday, but just some. I cant work it out.
I even disconnected the phone from any network connection and it grabs some of the images from yesterday (even though I have deleted and re-install the app as well!

Comment: Sounds like you're behind a firewall/proxy that's doing some caching as well then. Deleting your application from the phone will wipe everything to do with that app including all cached data. The random query string on the Uri should (In most cases) also get around proxy caching too so it may solve all your problems.

Comment: Can confirm this works in WP8 too. Had the same problem for an ImageBrush (needed to nest it in a Border control), but have found using an Image object instead also solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add a unique querystring parameter to the URL.  (eg, `DateTime.Now`)

Answer (score 1):

There is [CreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.createoptions(v=VS.95).aspx) property on [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=VS.95).aspx) (if you are loading in code) which lets you specify [BitmapCreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions(v=VS.95).aspx),one of which is **IgnoreImageCache**: *Loads images without using an existing image cache. This option should only be selected when images in a cache need to be refreshed.*

I've not tried it out, but it sounds like the kind of thing you are looking for ... if you do try it, I'd be interested in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you have control over the website and its content; shouldn't this be handled by setting the HTTP Response headers?
I would assume the platform respects the headers (unverified).

Otherwise the above posted random string trick will work.

Answer (score -1):

Cache is a good thing , cause in your case, it can save the cost to download the image, if the image is not change, why you need to download it again?

if your image had been changed, and you want to enforce to download it again, you can generate a unique id at the url.

but think about it, why?